# The bigest decimal place recomended for SPL-Token, and what type to use for it insteead of u64 to prevent overflows in math?

Tags: spl-token, decimal

I have a question about **token decimals**, as I could not find a clear answer to it. Is there some **recommended maximum** of the token decimal on Solana, by default it has **9**? If it will be bigger, for example, 18 to be compatible with Ethereum tokens, could it be that in the contract we need to use a bigger type than u64 to prevent overflow in math operations, for example, some u128 or u256 if they exist? What is the best practice here, maybe, if possible share some examples of projects where a bigger type than u64 is used for token operations? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can represent 18 decimal places in a 64-bit integer.

If you put `2^64` into [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%282%5E64%29) then you'll get its scientific notation: `1.8446744073709551616 × 10^19`. The 19 tells you that it can represent `10^19`, which is greater than `10^18`. Therefore every number between 0 and `10^18` can be represented by a `u64`.

Comment: Thank you, but if it will be a bigger decimal? Is it make sense at all and is there some recommendation for the max number of decimals?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's anything documented, but if you look at the token program source code it uses u64: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program/src/instruction.rs#L107 - so if you want your token to use that then it's limited by u64. So I'd say 19 is the max supported decimal value based on my answer, but I don't know of any official documentation/recommendations to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

While @callum-m's post is accurate, it should be noted that the max supply of a token with `decimals` set to `18` will be `18` whole units.  This is probably not what you want.  I would suggest instead working backwards from your intended max whole units supply and choose the `decimals` such that max supply base units still fit in a `u64`.

```
max_decimals = floor(log10(2^64/max_whole_units_supply))
```

So if you want a max whole units supply of `100M`, the max decimals would be `11`